# OpenGL Invalid Operation

Tags: opengl, opentk

I'm having an issue loading/assigning interleaved vertex data in OpenGL.

I keep getting an INVALID_OPERATION when setting the second attribute.

**EDIT**  Turns out this only happens on Mac.  On Windows, I don't get an INVALID_OPERATION error.  But I have modified the below with what it looks like now.  Still errors out on Mac.

```
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.GetAttribLocation("position"), 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, _vertexStride, 0);
        REngine.CheckGLError();
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.GetAttribLocation("normal"), 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, _vertexStride, 12);
        REngine.CheckGLError();
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(shader.GetAttribLocation("texcoord"), 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, _vertexStride, 24);
        REngine.CheckGLError();
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.GetAttribLocation("position"));
        REngine.CheckGLError();
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.GetAttribLocation("normal"));
        REngine.CheckGLError();
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(shader.GetAttribLocation("texcoord"));
        REngine.CheckGLError();
```

Any idea why?  Others seem to do it and it works great, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my GLSL for this:

```
layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location=2) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec4 out_position;
out vec4 out_normal;
out vec2 out_texcoord;


void main() {
  out_normal = vec4(normal,1.0f);
  out_position = vec4(position,1.0f);
  out_texcoord = texcoord;

}
```

and the frag:

```
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
  color = vec4(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
}
```

**EDIT**

*Turns out I had stale glErrors in the queue from earlier in the pipeline.  I checked earlier and had a bum call to glEnableClientState which isn't supported on Mac using the 4.2 context.  I removed it as it wasn't necessary anymore with a full shader approach.  This fixed the error and my glorious white mesh was displayed.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only active attributes have a location. Your `normal` attribute is not active, as it is not used (the fact that you forward it to `out_normal` is irrelevant, as `out_normal` is not used). `glGetAttributeLocation` will return -1 for that, but the attribute index for `glVertexAttribPointer` is a `GLuint`, and `(GLuint)-1` is way out of the range for allowed attribute indices. You should get the same error for `texcoord` too.

Please also note that using `sizeof(float)` as the `size` parameter for `glVertexAttribPointer` is wrong too. That parameter determines the number of components for the attribute vector, 1 (scalar), 2d, 3d or 4d, not some number of bytes.

Comment: I've already verified that the locations are set in my shader objects as 0, 1, 2 like my shader instructs.  Changing from sizeof(float) for the size to actual values like 3 doesn't help either.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you set them to. The attribuites are not active, so they won't have a location. No way around that. Note that, since you assigned the locations in the shader, you don't need `glGetAttribLocation` at all. YOu can simply use 0, 1 and 2 - and no error will occur, as all those numbers are valid, while `(GLuint)-1` isn't.

Comment: Turns out I had stale glErrors I wasn't checking until after the calls to set the interleaved data.  I moved the check further up the pipeline and caught an old glEnableClientState call which isn't supported on Mac.  It's actually not even necessary since I use a full shader approach.  But I'm going to go ahead and say this question is answered as you are indeed correct about the active attributes.